# `-initialize` flag no longer works in mylatexformat?

Tags: command-line

It was suggested in `mylatexformat` documentation to use `-initialize` flag.

[image: mylatexformat documentation]

However, it appears that in some newer version, this stopped working. (experimentally, `-ini` still works)

What caused the change?

Comment: (And maybe someone can update the package documentation? The last update to the package is 12 years ago, I'm not sure if it's possible to contact the author anymore?)

Comment: As the subsection title says that is a miktex option, and it still works (but miktex also recognize `--ini`). In texlive it was imho never (my oldest system from 2012 doesn't know it).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, I must have misremembered then. My fault.  (I could probably delete the question but it's not infeasible that someone stumble across the same issue reading the documentation...)